# convert io.BytesIO type to werkzeug.datastructures FileStrorage type Flask

Tags: python, werkzeug

how to convert io.BytesIo type to werkzeug.datastructures FileStrorage type Flask

I've tried to do simple conversion with casting FileStorage(File) but the return is none

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It would be nice if you provided an example of your use case.

To convert an object of type `BytesIO` into a [`FileStorage`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) object I recommend the following method.

```py
data = bytes([1,2,3,4,5,6])
file = FileStorage(
    stream=io.BytesIO(data), 
    filename='filename.dat', 
    content_type='application/octet-stream', 
    content_length=len(data)
)
print(file, file.read())
```